# Represent dynamically added form fields in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm having a hard time representing the following situation in the database:

**A user can declare multiple addresses (such as Home, Office, Mailing etc. as requested by client).**

I have an auto-incremented primary key called `UserID` that represents one user account. I've been thinking of making a `BelongsToUserID` column to represent each user's form field to look like:

[image: Desired database structure]

I can't do this because each row can only be occupied by `UserID` row. 
Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a separate table holding the addresses. Perhaps something like:

| id(primary key) | type(enum home/work/etc.) | userID | address |

Comment: This makes most sense, it's most manageable and it's taking advantage of all that is good about databases being relative.

Store addresses in this other table and the linking reference will be the user ID.

As juco says you can store the: aid (address unique id), address type, address, userid 

Much faster and more maintainable in future

Comment: @Paul - I have a question, how do I go around the situation where the address table will contain `UserID` (the database's main primary key) and making a new primary key like `AddressID`?

Comment: @thekalaban databases don't have primary keys, tables do. Your users table will of course have a primary key, and it's likely you will want one in your address table too. It's also common practice just to call this column `id`

Comment: @juco - Now I get it! My term *database's main primary key* actually refers to all the tables having the same primary key for easier access. I know now that it's bad practice lol Thank you very much!

Comment: @juco - Another question: If `UserID` has been updated in another table, how do I sync it with the `UserID` inside the address table during input?

Comment: If UserID is a primary key in the users table, it shouldn't be updated , meaning the UserID value in the address table should not need to be updated..

Answer (score 0):

you can make this in two ways

first one is simple but not adviced is that you don't make any primary key and use composite key pair as the candidate key and choose primary from that. as the table is missing the primary key its not adviced

second approach is good and i also use that is to make a master table and use that as the relation-table there and use another table to actually store the data.

in master table you can have id, userid, address_bit, and in second table you can have id, address_bit, address.

please tell me any other solution if you found one. It might help me to learn new :)

Comment: I agree, I do not want to use primary key-less tables. BTW I'll go with the accepted answer as it only occupies one table to accommodate the problem :) Thanks again!